# Find the max value between minimum values in sub-arrays

Tags: python, array

I have an array of integers, I have to find all sub-arrays of different size from `1` to `len(array)`. In every sub-array, I have to find the minimum value in it, once done I have to find the maximum value between the minimum values of all the subarrays of the same size. Finally, I have to return these maximum values in a list.

So the first value in my list will always be the maximum integer in the array, the second value will be the maximum between the minimum values of the sub-arrays size 2, and so on; the last value in the list will always be the minimum integer of the array.
Original problem here: [Min Max Riddle](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/min-max-riddle/problem)

```py
def min_max_subarrays(arr):
    result = [max(arr), ]
    w = 2
    while w < len(arr):
      temp = 0
      for i, n in enumerate(arr[:-w+1]):
        x = min(arr[i:i+w])
        if x > temp:
          temp = x
      result.append(temp)
      w += 1
    result.append(min(arr))
    return result
```

The function is correct but I'm sure there's a way to reduce time complexity. I feel one loop is unnecessary but I'm struggling to find a way to remove it.

Comment: I corrected the indentation (It was a copy/paste error), yes it is online somewhere but I did it a while ago and don't remember where it is... If my explanation isn't clear I can search for the original.

Comment: I found it: "Min Max Riddle" on Hackerrank

Comment: I see. So one important thing you omitted is the limits. n=10^6 rules out not only cubic time solutions like yours but also quadratic time ones.

Comment: Perhaps add the link to hackerrank in question too.

Comment: also, check the discussions on the same for a hint on \$ O(n) \$ solution https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/min-max-riddle/forum/comments/486316

Comment: By 'the maximum between' do you mean 'the maximum OF' or 'the maximum of the pairwise subtraction'?

Comment: "the maximum of", also there's a link with all the details